# Location by using getLAstKnownLocation

Tags: android, locationmanager

Iam using a location manager in my code, but Iam not using the onLocationChanged() method while I have a method that repeats every second and it requests the location thru locationManager.getLastKnowLocation.....
It works fine and every second it get the location acuratly, the issue when I take the cell phone indoor of course the location is not availabel while my app still get the location of the last point I was outdoor as it always getLastKnowLocation.
Any idea how to fix this issue

Comment: Did you use both two permission to get your position are: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

Comment: The `getLastKnownLocation()` method just gets the last known location that the device happens to know. The device doesn't determine its location on its own, but only when some application requests the location. So your app is now dependent on other applications requesting location updates. If you need regular location updates, then request regular location updates yourself and use the `onLocationChanged()` callback. The [documentation section](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/1837/location#t=201610120710565214353) has code examples.

Comment: Yes, Iam using android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />